# How to check compressed size of image from insecure registry before docker pull?

Tags: docker

There are ways to check compressed image size before pulling from Docker Hub, but in order to do the same for an insecure/domain registry, how can I check the download size before pull?

While doing a pull, I can see size of each layer being downloaded like this, which I can sum up to find total size.

```sh
7595c8c21622: Already exists
d13af8ca898f: Already exists
70799171ddba: Already exists
b6c12202c5ef: Already exists
ef50ae158fa8: Downloading [===============>                                   ]  74.18MB/239.3MB
e5665f29b73a: Downloading [=>                                                 ]  95.26MB/2.741GB
780c121f1da3: Downloading [========>                                          ]  75.27MB/462.5MB
5fc49bebd483: Waiting
592ff9f385a7: Waiting
80a3934684b4: Waiting
b523362dbfaa: Waiting
3bf96686ba27: Waiting
dd64f3b98c5f: Waiting
937238fb3569: Waiting
c39efc826c40: Waiting
```

But I would like to know beforehand what would be the total download size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker pushes a manifest file for each image on the registry, containing checksum, size and misc info, which all download clients use, in order to pull layers.

Given your registry/image name, you can `inspect` the manifest file, sum up the sizes of each layer to get the total download size.

First, enable Docker's experimental CLI features.

1. To temporarily enable:

   `export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled`
2. Make it permanent:

   Add `"experimental": "enabled"` in `~/.docker/config.json`

Check size:

```sh
docker manifest inspect --insecure -v <registry_or_domain>/<image_name> | grep size | awk -F ':' '{sum+=$NF} END {print sum}' | xargs printf "%f\n" | numfmt --to=iec
```

`printf` formats the scientific notation of size (like 3e+09) to a float, which `numfmt` can parse.